# SQL create custom rank in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am trying to create a custom rank or order in my query so I can see the sequence of events chronologically grouped by user. What I am trying to achieve is the order under "Desired_Rank" but I've only been able to create the last 2 columns. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
dense_rank() OVER( ORDER BY date ,user_id) Current_Rank_1
dense_rank() OVER( ORDER BY user_id) Current_Rank_2


User_ID   Date      Desired_Rank    Current_Rank_1   Current_Rank_2
  a     12/23/2016     1               1                  1
  b     12/27/2016     2               2                  2
  a     2/24/2017      3               3                  1
  c     2/24/2017      4               4                  3
  d     5/3/2017       5               5                  4
  d     5/5/2017       5               6                  4
  d     5/9/2017       5               7                  4
  d     5/9/2017       5               7                  4
```

Comment: Sorry, Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `lag` and a running sum. Comparing the current row's user_id with the previous user_id and resetting the value if a change is encountered.

```
select t.*,sum(col) over(order by date) as rnk
from (select t.*
     ,case when lag(user_id) over(order by date) = user_id then 0 else 1 end as col
      from tbl t
     ) t
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. Thank you for the suggestion.